# Deployment of a Java EE app on the server

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, jakarta-ee

i'm trying to deploy my app on the server, but I still get those errors:

```
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlNamespaceAware' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host} Setting property 'xmlValidation' to 'false' did not find a matching property.
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'debug' to '99' did not find a matching property.
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:lombok.demo' did not find a matching property.
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
AVERTISSEMENT: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context/Manager} Setting property 'pathName' to '' did not find a matching property.
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFOS: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFOS: Initialization processed in 717 ms
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFOS: Démarrage du service Catalina
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:34 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFOS: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.62
avr. 28, 2016 12:00:35 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

Does someone have an idea what it could be?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: when you get this error ?

Comment: There are no errors at all.

Comment: I did a maven install ( build succes ) after that run on server and got this.

Comment: But i cannot acces the web page in the browser.

Comment: How are you packaging your application? JAR, WAR, EAR?